# How to get the data of the first element of ObservableCollection in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm making a floating button with a CollectionView and adding the data in an ObservableCollection. In the first index of the ObservableCollection, I have links. My idea is get the links of the first index, and depends of the button you touch, go to the link they have in the list.

ViewModel.cs:

```
 public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    public ObservableCollection<Items> ItemList { get; set; }

    string imageprimarybutton;
    public string ImagePrimaryButton{ get => imageprimarybutton; set {
            imageprimarybutton = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } }
    public string ColorPrimaryButton { get; set; }

    public Command OpenFloating { get; }

    public Command LaunchWeb { get; }

    private bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get => isVisible;
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public ViewModel() {

        OpenFloating = new Command(openFloatingButton);
        LaunchWeb = new Command(openApp);
        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Items>();

        IsVisible = false;

        ImagePrimaryButton = "dots.png";

        ColorPrimaryButton = "#B52D50";

       // All images must be the same resolution(256x256 recommended, trim the image is recommended)         
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website="https://facebook.com",Image="facebook.png",ColorButton= "#B52D50" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://google.com", Image = "twitter.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://twitter.com", Image = "insta.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" });
        ItemList.Add(new Items { Website = "https://instagram.com", Image = "linkedin.png", ColorButton = "#B52D50" });
       


    }

    Boolean firstStart = true;
    Boolean nextClick = true;

    public void openFloatingButton()
    {


        if (firstStart)
        {
            ImagePrimaryButton = "cross.png";
            IsVisible = true;
            firstStart = false;

        }
        else
        {


            if (nextClick)
            {
                ImagePrimaryButton = "dots.png";
                IsVisible = false;
                nextClick = false;

            }
            else
            {
                ImagePrimaryButton = "cross.png";
                IsVisible = true;
                nextClick = true;

            }



        }
    }

    public void openApp()
    {
     //Method to get the link and go to the url

    }


}
```

MainPage.xaml:

[MainPage.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNf76.png)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> depends of the button you touch, go to the link they have in the list.

If you want to open the url that define in the property **Website** when user click the ImageButton , you could pass the Website as **CommandParameter**

#### in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx"
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage"
             
             x:Name="page"  // set name of ContentPage
             
             >
```

```
 <ImageButton
                
       Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference page},Path=BindindContext.LaunchWeb}"
       CommandParameter="{Binding Website}"
       //...
                
    />
```

#### in ViewModel

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

```
public ICommand LaunchWeb { get; private set; }
```

```
LaunchWeb = new Command(async(url)=> {
            
   //url here is the website of the item that you click 
   // now you can do something you want

  string AppLink = (string)url;

  await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(AppLink);
            
 });
```